# Delete link wrong hover text on my own post

Tags: support

When I hover over a delete link on my post(answer or question), I see that the hover text is saying `Vote to delete this post`. Is this wrong or am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: It's not technically *wrong* but, because it's your post, your vote is binding.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, it is a vote.

In this case, as it is your post, only one vote is needed, but it is a delete vote nonetheless.

Comment: I think this is true from a technical experience, but a user who wants to delete his own post shouldn't have to process this info to realize what he is about to do.